# pandas groupby unexpectedly returns negative sum

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have data on port freight volumes by year that I wish to sum to turn into percentages later on, but I find I get negative sums unexpectedly:

```
data = pd.Series(
{('2006', 'Oakland, CA (Port)'): 7460155164,
 ('2006', 'Rest of California'): 32868692124,
 ('2006', 'San Francisco, CA (Port)'): 2262901767,
 ('2007', 'Oakland, CA (Port)'): 7881218797,
 ('2007', 'Rest of California'): 38595482723,
 ('2007', 'San Francisco, CA (Port)'): 1897361592,
 ('2008', 'Oakland, CA (Port)'): 8325019179,
 ('2008', 'Rest of California'): 46200094019,
 ('2008', 'San Francisco, CA (Port)'): 2732413994,
 ('2009', 'Oakland, CA (Port)'): 9077952296,
 ('2009', 'Rest of California'): 42642020668,
 ('2009', 'San Francisco, CA (Port)'): 2998130982,
 ('2010', 'Oakland, CA (Port)'): 9596205900,
 ('2010', 'Rest of California'): 48091887406,
 ('2010', 'San Francisco, CA (Port)'): 2623519555,
 ('2011', 'Oakland, CA (Port)'): 10316313358,
 ('2011', 'Rest of California'): 54869935898,
 ('2011', 'San Francisco, CA (Port)'): 2591413704})
data
```

This series behaves as expected:

```
data.sum(level=0)
Out[27]:
2006    42591749055
2007    48374063112
2008    57257527192
2009    54718103946
2010    60311612861
2011    67777662960
dtype: int64
```

or, using `groupby:

```
data.groupby(level=0).sum()


Out[26]:
2006    42591749055
2007    48374063112
2008    57257527192
2009    54718103946
2010    60311612861
2011    67777662960
dtype: int64
```

I want to apply this:
lambda x: x/x.sum() to do within-group percentages, but `x.sum()` gives unexpected results: When I sum in a lambda function, I get *negative* values:

```
data.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.sum())

Out[28]:
2006    -357923905
2007    1129422856
2008    1422952344
2009   -1116470902
2010     182070717
2011    -941813776
dtype: int64
```

For the record, things look healthy with the grouping itself, returning expected sets of values:

```
data.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: [x])
Out[21]:
2006     [[7460155164, 32868692124, 2262901767]]
2007     [[7881218797, 38595482723, 1897361592]]
2008     [[8325019179, 46200094019, 2732413994]]
2009     [[9077952296, 42642020668, 2998130982]]
2010     [[9596205900, 48091887406, 2623519555]]
2011    [[10316313358, 54869935898, 2591413704]]
dtype: object
```

But why the negative sums?

Comment: Which operating system? It works fine on Ubuntu / Python 3.6.

Comment: Windows 7. But the datatype is `dtype: int64` so I should be way below the danger territory here. Also, python 2.7.

Comment: Does `data.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: type(x[0]))` also return `int64`?

Comment: @ayhan yup, `2006    <type 'numpy.int64'>`

Comment: This also works fine for me on windows 10 python 2.7

Comment: Just tried on ubuntu as well, also python 2.7. Works as intended there. I still don't understand why these numbers seemingly result in a silent overflow when calling the lambda sum. Maybe that one is numpy, the others aren't? Still doesn't explain it.